# Consistency guarantees of Cosmos DB in local region

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmos db instance with only one read region and write region. In my case, what do the consistency guarantees provided by Cosmos DB mean?

To be precise, I do a write W to a document. I do a read R on the same document. If I have chosen 'Eventual Consistency', is there a possibility that I see a write older than W even if I have a single read and write region?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed. The consistency levels aren't just on the georeplication but also the single region.

You can see by the way that Microsoft visualizes the different consistency levels with music notes that (in a single region):

- Strong and bounded staleness will give you strong consistency on a single region
- Session will only give you strong consistency within a single session. Anything outsite the session can have stale reads.
- Consistent Prefix and Eventual can both have stale reads.

Comment: Hi famous YouTuber :) So if you only have an Cosmos DB account in a single region, does it makes sense to chose other than the default Session? I have read that replica writes within a single region happens blazingly fast, like 1 ms.